# Eclipse: Error importing android-support-v7-appcompat to workspace

Tags: android, android-support-library, eclipse-adt

I'm new. I use Eclipse.

As it is shown in several video tutorials.

File> Import -> Existing Android Project -> (Route sdk / extas / android / support / v7 / appcompat).

Imports almost all very well, however these errors appear within me res / values-v21

[2015-11-04 02:35:50 - android-support-v7-appcompat] D:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:131: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.

[2015-11-04 02:35:50 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-11-04 02:35:50 - android-support-v7-appcompat] D:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:140: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.

[2015-11-04 02:35:50 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-11-04 02:35:50 - android-support-v7-appcompat] D:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:144: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.

[2015-11-04 02:35:50 - android-support-v7-appcompat]

PS: I have updated all my extras. SDK Tools, Android and Android Support Support Repository Library.

Comment: why use eclipse if you can use android studio? more small ram, easy to setup library,and its official

Answer (score 0):

Just open the project.properties file of the android-support-v7-appcompat and change the target from target=android-19 to target=android-21.
Afterwards just do a Project --> Clean... so that the changes take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use `Android studio`.
Here is the answer for your problem in eclipse:
Right click on `android-support-v7-appcompat`, go to `Properties` -> `Android`. Make sure that API 21 is selected. If not selected, select it and click on `Apply` -> `Ok` and it should fix those errors.